# How to add CardView to a Navigation Drawer Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have been trying to add `CardView` to `navigationDrawer activity` and `collapsing toolbar layout` all in one activity so that I can view all my contents form navigation drawer and collapse the layout and use card view as my buttons to make it more attractive. but it works fine as long as I don't add card views into the layout, but when I add the `CardView` into the code that is `XML` file and run the program the emulator shows that the app has not responding.

I need help with this, please anyone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.madhu.management.DashBoard">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e0e0e0">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/materialappbar"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="480dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:title="management">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fcfcfc"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpurple"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_alert_white_24px" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Notice"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="department notice board"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpink"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_book_white_24px" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Notes"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Notes from faculty"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundgreen"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_help_outline_white_24px" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Question papers"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Question banks and question papers"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundyellow"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_update_white_24px" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="University Updates"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="updates from university"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="340dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/circlebackgroundpurple"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_stars_white_24dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Results"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="semister results"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: your layout code is working fine, post your activity code

Comment: i haven added any code in activity yet. but it works fine in the tutorial i saw.

Comment: public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

Comment: sorry to post the code in this way. i was unable to post the code at once